# Loading from Power Query to Data Model with Excel 32 bit

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

Is it possible for you who use Excel 32 bit (check File-->Account-->About Excel) to load from Power Query to the Data Model and update the query afterwards?

My private office is 64 bit and everything works, but at my work we have 32 bit and even very small queries (only 10 rows) will not load or update when loading to the data model.

Wondering if it is generally not possible or maybe something wrong with the office installation.

[image]

Comment: Maybe there's something about your particular query.  I have 32-bit Excel. I just took an existing query; loaded it to the data model, and had no problem refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

You can roll back to the earlier version of Excel to see if it works.